# Global variable seems by be corrupted by executing a recursive code

Tags: python, variables, recursion, scope, global

I am new to Python. I can't figure out why a global variable seems by be corrupted by executing a recursive code.

```
globVar = []

def explore(X, Y):
        global globVar
        globVar = X
        print()
        print("set: "+str(X))   # This is the only place where the global variable is set
        for i in range(1, 5):
            X[Y] = i
            if Y < 2:
                print("  =? " + str(globVar) + " <<< Here has the next global value. Why? Global Var should't do that!")
                explore(X, Y + 1)
                print("  =? " + str(globVar) + " OK here")


# Launch recursive exploration
explore([1,1,1],0)
```

Here is an extract of what the previous code returns:

```
...
set: [1, 2, 4]
  =? [1, 2, 4] OK here
  =? [1, 3, 4] <<< Here has the next global value. Why? Global Var should't do that!

set: [1, 3, 4]
...
```

Any idea why globVar seems to be impacted by the context of the recursion?

I would have expected its value to be simply the last value set.
But this is not what the printout shows.

Thank you guys/gals!

Answer (score 0):

The variable `X` and  `globVar` refer to the *same* single list. So when you do:

```
X[Y] = i
```

You are mutating that same single list. You might as well have written:

```
globVar[Y] = i
```

It would have exactly the same effect.

So, you should create a *new* list. For instance, you could do:

```
globVar = X[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following:

```
>>> s = set([1,2,3])
>>> x = s
>>> s.add(4)
>>> s
{1, 2, 3, 4}
>>> x
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

The assignment `x = s` does not create a *copy* of the set that was assigned to `s`. In fact what *was* assigned to `s`? Nothing but a *reference* or pointer to a place in memory where that set resides. So, the assignment `x = s` is simply copying that reference making `x` point to the same set that `s` is pointing to. Now when you modify the set that `s` is referring to, you are modifying the set that `x` is referring to.

But here you are creating a new set, i.e. a copy of the set that `s` is pointing to, and assigning a pointer to that new set to `x`:

```
>>> s = set([1,2,3])
>>> x = s.copy()
>>> s.add(4)
>>> s
{1, 2, 3, 4}
>>> x
{1, 2, 3}
```

This is the way assignment of objects works in Python works whether those objects are sets, lists, dictionaries, etc. or your own defined class instances.

Answer (score 0):

Always check if

```
globVar is X
```

If you try that you can see that the `globVar` and `X` are the pointers to the same exact piece of information in memory.

If you change `globVar`, `X` also gets changed.
If you wish to avoid that and have separate copies for both, you must do

```
globVar = X[:]
```

Now the `globVar is X` is false and you can safely change one without affecting the other.